# When packaging an RPM, do I put my tests in SOURCES?

Tags: rhel, rpm, packaging

The RPM build directory tree is:

```
$ tree ~/rpmbuild/
/home/user/rpmbuild/
|-- BUILD
|-- RPMS
|-- SOURCES
|-- SPECS
`-- SRPMS
```

If I want to have a test that's not installed in the system but is used by `%CHECK` do I place it in `SOURCES`? Take for example a perl project's `./t` directory, or JavaScript project `./tests` directory? Where should I place that?

Answer (score 5):

You wouldn’t manually place them anywhere. Assuming they’re included in the upstream tarball you use, they will be extracted during the build, and the `%check` part will use the extracted tests.

`SOURCES` contains the downloaded files corresponding to `Source:` stanzas in your `.spec` file. The various directories are used as follows, in this order:

- `SPECS` contains `.spec` files, which fully describe an RPM build
- `SOURCES` contains files corresponding to the `Source:` lines in `.spec` files
- `SRPMS` contains source RPMs built from `.spec` files and source files (archives, patches etc.)
- `BUILD` contains the build tree extracted from SRPMs
- `RPMS` contains the binary RPMs built from build trees

Comment: What if we're doing something really weird, like developing inside a rpm SOURCES directory? Should they the tests for that code be inside SOURCES too? or outside?

Comment: What does your `.spec` file look like? Specifically, the `Source:` lines?